# What is a Bw-tree?

Tags: sql-server, database, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have just read a paper on "in memory OLTP" for the next version of SQL server; it mentions BW-Tree as being added as well as hash indexes in CTP2.

So what is a BW-Tree? Can someone explain a bit about it without me (and everyone else) having to read a 12 page research paper.

Comment: Higher level: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/justinle/papers/ICDE2013_bwtree.pptx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From Microsoft:

> Our new form of B tree, called the Bw-tree achieves its very high performance via a latch-free approach that effectively exploits the processor caches of modern multi-core chips. Our storage manager uses a unique form of log structuring that blurs the distinction between a page and a record store and works well with flash storage.

You can read the PDF [Here](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/178758/bw-tree-icde2013-final.pdf)

Comment: I experienced some increased storage use with this indexing technique, can you confirm this is related to bw-tree indexing?

Answer (score 19):

In a nutshell, a bw-tree is a kind of b-tree that is optimized for in-memory and for high concurrency.
For in-memory: the pages are variable-size and always tightly packed; there are no partially-filled pages
For high-concurrency: the data structure is completely latch- and lock-free to support concurrent DML without blocking.

Comment: It also trades faster writes for slower reads, but it makes sense when the tree can be stored on SSD at some point.